# Reducing database rows for aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table:

`+ID+Duration+Cost_change+Def_cost+
| 1| 0.10 | 0.191 | 13.700  |
| 2| 0.15 | 0.291 | 21.200  |
| 3| 0.14 | 0.043 | 17.500  |
| 4| 0.10 | 2.131 | 19.000  |
| 5| 0.10 | 3.000 | 11.000  |
| 6| 0.19 | 1.100 | 18.500  |
| 7| 0.10 | 0.000 | 14.000  |
| 8| 0.10 | 0.000 | 13.000  |
| 9| 0.18 | 0.000 | 15.000  |
|10| 0.10 | 4.100 | 12.000  |
|11| 0.14 | 0.000 | 9.800   |
|12| 0.10 | 0.000 | 7.000   |
+---------+-------+--------+`

I have an extra column(groups) which groups values by 3 rows  1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4 and so on. Later I'll have to aggregate(SUM,AVG) values by these groups. Aim - to reduce number of rows in 3 times (without losing data).
Will be grateful for any advise.

Expect:

`+ID+Duration+Cost_change+Def_cost+Groups
  | 1| 0.10 | 0.191 | 13.700 |  1
  | 2| 0.15 | 0.291 | 21.200 |  1
  | 3| 0.14 | 0.043 | 17.500 |  1
  | 4| 0.10 | 2.131 | 19.000 |  2
  | 5| 0.10 | 3.000 | 11.000 |  2
  | 6| 0.19 | 1.100 | 18.500 |  2
  | 7| 0.10 | 0.000 | 14.000 |  3
  | 8| 0.10 | 0.000 | 13.000 |  3
  | 9| 0.18 | 0.000 | 15.000 |  3
  |10| 0.10 | 4.100 | 12.000 |  4
  |11| 0.14 | 0.000 | 9.800  |  4
  |12| 0.10 | 0.000 | 7.000  |  4
  +---------+-------+--------+`

Simple sequence by 3 values.

I'm using `SQL Server 2012`

Comment: Can you please post expected result and what you tried so far.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: your problem is to generate the `Groups`-column?

Comment: without losing data? you will not see your individual records.. you are good with that?

Comment: @DarkKnight , Some data will be lost of course, but I'll aggregate and have avg values

Comment: @Aツ , yeah, I need to get Groups field with sequence values by 3

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too long for a comment.

But, if you want to add the column `groups`, you can just do:

```
select 1 + ((id - 1) / 3) as groups
```

If the `id` values could have holes, use `row_number()` instead:

```
select 1 + (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) / 3 as groups
```

SQL Server does integer division, so this assigns the values as you have specified.